# Objective-C: How does one memorize every method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

So I been watching tutorials on iOS development and it seems that every instructor in the video seem to have a good memory for methods in Objective-C which surprises me by the fact that every now and then I am working on a small project and I forget how to call a specific method like to append an NSString or to hide the TabBar from the bottom screen.

An instructor in a video seems to know which method to call whereas I wouldn't even think of calling that same method. For example, when the instructor creates an example iOS app to either leave no spaces in an NSString on a UITextfield, he would use a method that U would forget every often down to even Googling it.

Is it me that my memory isn't great since i am not exposed to methods often or do people study methods in order to fully have them all ready when a certain task should be done?

I feel that my mind isn't fully capable to memorize things like an instructor would with such an ease that it seems he can go by knowing a lot in Obj-C.

How would one get to know more on iOS and be able to memorize method calling without actually having to go to the trouble of trying to memorize them?

Comment: First you should have a good general knowledge of software development. Then you should understand the Objective-C naming conventions and you just learn most of the API. I do not memorize every method and have to search in the apple docs from time to time. and there is nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Personally, I don't do anything extraordinary to remember methods. Eventually, the more you practice, you just kind of remember. I do recommend checking out the Apple docs though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry it'll come. You just need to practice, use xcode autocompletion and built-in doc.

In xcode just hit command + space to get available methods for the leading symbol.

Anyway nobody knows every methods by heart. You'll just end up remembering the ones you use the most.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are people doing videos have written a script for what they are going to. Including the steps, this is probably why they can recall methods that quickly. It's also something that comes from experience, as you begin to do more and more in Obj-C you will start to learn method names. It's unlikely that most people will memorise ALL of them but that's what the documentation is for + google :-)

Comment: Most of the time I just remember the start of a method or a similar one and let code sense/intelli sense do the work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would say its impossible to memorize ALL methods, but as you keep coding you keep remembering more and more methods or ways of achieving things. I remember when i was just a beginner and the basic method "removeFromSuperview" was something new to me. In time, you learn much more complicated methods and since you basically use them everyday (if your not copying your code from somewhere) you learn them quite easy. So my answer - in time you can memorize anything but not everything.

Comment: Definetly will use resources such a notebook to pin out the methods i would find most useful. Like prepareForSegue and other methods

Comment: Please comment reasons for down votes. Thanks.

Comment: user2994008 - Thats a good way to learn them too.